# Yii2 как разрешить гостям доступ к действию

Tags: yii2, yii

В контроллере прописаны такие разрешения

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => QueryParamAuth::className(),
        'tokenParam' => 'access-token',
    ];
    $behaviors['access'] = [
        'class' => AccessControl::className(),
        'rules' => [
            [
                'actions' => ['index'],
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['?'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
        'cors' => [
            'Origin' => ['*'],
            'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
            'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
            'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 86400,
        ],
    ];

    return $behaviors;
}
```

При попытке обратиться к действию index не авторизованным пользователем выдает ошибку.`401 Your request was made with invalid credentials.`

Что я делаю не так, почему не пропускает гостей?

Вот ещё один вариант с 'only' => 'index'

```
$behaviors['access'] = [
        'class' => AccessControl::className(),
        'only' => ['index'],
        'rules' => [
            [
                'actions' => ['index'],
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['?'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: Попробуйте в `$behaviors['access']` добавить
   `'only' =>  ['index' ],`

Comment: Добавлял, это не помогает

Comment: А чего вы хотите добиться и зачем Вам вообще эти Behaviors в данном случае?

Comment: Я хочу чтоб actionIndex() в моем контроллере был доступен не авторизованным пользователям (гостям). Я делаю всё по документации, не понимаю почему это не работает

Answer (score 0):

Перед добавлением поведения авторизации, добавь проверку на наличие данных об авторизации

```
if (Yii::$app->request->get('access-token') !== null)
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => QueryParamAuth::className(),
        'tokenParam' => 'access-token',
    ];
```

или

```
if (Yii::$app->request->headers->get('Authorization') !== null)
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBasicAuth::class,
        ];
```

Так же при создании запроса, нужно указать, что пользовательские данные не будут использоваться

```
fetch(url, {mode: 'no-cors'})
```